# Unmarshalling JSON into Go interface{}

Tags: json, go, memcached

I have this struct with a field of type `interface{}`. In the process of caching it using memcached (https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache), the struct is marshalled into a JSON, which is then unmarshalled back into the struct when retrieved from the cache. The resulting `interface{}` field inevitably points to an object of type map[string]interface{} (as in, the `interface{}` field can only type asserted as map[string]interface{}), the marshalling and unmarshalling process not having preserved the type information. Is there any way to save this information in the marshalling process, in such a way that it can be unmarshalled properly? Or do I have to use some other codec or something?

```
type A struct {
    value interface{}
}

type B struct {
    name string
    id string
}

func main() {
    a := A{value: B{name: "hi", id: "12345"}}
    cache.Set("a", a) // Marshals 'a' into JSON and stores in cache
    result = cache.Get("a") // Retrieves 'a' from cache and unmarshals
    fmt.Printf("%s", result.value.(B).name) // Generates error saying that 
        // map[string]interface{} cannot be type asserted as a 'B' struct
    fmt.Printf("%s", result.value.(map[string]interface{})["name"].(string)) // Correctly prints "12345"
}
```

Comment: Should the title be: _Unmarshalling_ JSON into Go interface{} ?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version, no you can't do that, you have few options though.

1. Change `A.Value` to use `B` instead of `interface{}`.
2. Add a function to `A` that converts `A.Value` from a map to `B` if it isn't already `B`.
3. Use `encoding/gob` and store the bytes in memcache then convert it back with a function like `NewA(b []byte) *A`.

For using `gob`, you have to register each struct with it first before encoding / decoding, [example](http://play.golang.org/p/Z5_m2kvIt1):

```
func init() {
    //where you should register your types, just once
    gob.Register(A{})
    gob.Register(B{})
}
func main() {
    var (
        buf bytes.Buffer
        enc = gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
        dec = gob.NewDecoder(&buf)
        val = A{B{"name", "id"}}
        r   A
    )
    fmt.Println(enc.Encode(&val))
    fmt.Println(dec.Decode(&r))
    fmt.Printf("%#v", r)
}
```

Comment: Hmm I guess I'll try gob. That function would be a pain to write and just take up space, not to mention error checking.

Comment: Hmm I'm not even sure that encoding/gob allows you to store the underlying type of an interface... May have to write the function anyway

Comment: It does, however You have to register each type with `gob.Register`.

Comment: oh awesome, missed that when looking through the docs, i skipped straight to encoder

Answer (score 2):

JSON isn't able to encode the depth of type information that you can in Go, so you'll always get back the following basic types when unmarshalling:

> bool, for JSON booleans
>
> float64, for JSON numbers
>
> string, for JSON strings
>
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
>
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
>
> nil for JSON null

From go docs: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

If *you* have that knowledge about the types you need, you can write some methods to construct the right variables on unmarshalling perhaps?